# Using inline-block instead of floating

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to **right-align** the nav without using float. I read somewhere online that I could set the parent element to `text-align: right`, but that didn't work when I tried it. I appreciate any help for what I know is an easy problem but one that has confounded me most of the day.

```css
header {
  background-color: #AEB7CC;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="hi.php">hi</a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>bop</li>
      <li>bop</li>
      <li>bop</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a6a367vp/

Comment: Did you try applying `text-align: right` to the `header` or the `nav`? Also, any particular reason why floats can't be used?

Comment: Um... it works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/a6a367vp/1/

Comment: @Juhana I'm guessing that the "hi" should be on the left since it's outside of the nav.

Comment: Although typically you'd apply the inline-block to the list elements, not the list itself.

Comment: @j08691 Well, "I read [..] that I could set the parent element" and header is the parent element.

Comment: @Litty: I started off using floats, but I was having a hard time getting the vertical alignment of the list items correct. I tried applying "text-align: right" to the nav. I didn't apply it to the header because I only want nav to be positioned to the right.

Comment: @Juhana: Yes, j08691 is correct. "Hi" needs to stay on the left. I want the nav to be positioned to the right.

Comment: This is exactly the problem floats was made for. Just my two cents: If you can figure out the vertical alignment problem, it would make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

One possible and recommended solution is as follows:

Put the `<nav>` in a `<div>` element and then use the `text-align` property for the specified div. like this:

Html:

```
<div class="nav_menu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li>bop</li>
        <li>bop</li>
        <li>bop</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav_menu{
  text-align: right;
}
```

**Update:**

Put the `<a>` tag in another div and then specify the width for the selected divs. Your final code should be like this:

HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="atag_div">
        <a href="hi.php">hi</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav_menu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li>bop</li>
        <li>bop</li>
        <li>bop</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: #AEB7CC;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
}

.atag_div{
    width: 20%; 
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav_menu{
  width: 78%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pokies/7Lnfq7es/

Answer (score 0):

<s>The solution is that you have to add `text-align: right;` to the parent element which is the `header`.</s>

```
header {
    text-align: right;
    ...
}
```

Then add `display: inline-block;` to the children (`nav`) and the children will be aligned right.

Another solution would be to set a width to `nav` and `a`:

```
header nav {
    with: 80%;
}

header a {
    width: 20%;
}

header nav ul {
    text-align: right;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the nav to move to the right, simple method is `float:right` but since you don't want to use this then `text-align:right` would place it on right if nav has `100% width` for that row.
Therefore, you can do either of these two things.

right now using **CSS** you can make

```
nav{width:98%; text-align:right};
```

or for better results, use **JS**

```
var anchorTopWidth = $("a").width() / $('a').parent().width() * 100;
requiredWidth = 100-anchorTopWidth;
$('nav').css({'width': requiredWidth+'%', 'text-align':'right'});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a6a367vp/3/